PIL: generate an image from applying a gradient to a NumPy array
I have a 2d NumPy array with values from 0 to 1. I want to turn this array into a Pillow image. I can do the following, which gives me a nice greyscale image:
arr = np.random.rand(100,100)
img = Image.fromarray((255 * arr).astype(np.uint8))

Now, instead of making a greyscale image, I'd like to apply a custom gradient.
To clarify, instead of drawing bands of colors in a linear gradient as in this example, I'd like to specify apply a gradient colormap to an existing 2d array and turn it into a 3d array.
Example: If my gradient is [color1, color2, color3], then all 0s should be color1, all 1s should be color3, and 0.25 should be somewhere in between color1 and color2. I was already able to write a simple function that does this:
gradient = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 80, 0), (0, 200, 255)] # black -> orange -> blue

def get_color_at(x):
    assert 0 <= x <= 1
    n = len(gradient)
    if x == 1:
        return gradient[-1]
    pos = x * (n - 1)
    idx1 = int(pos)
    idx2 = idx1 + 1
    frac = pos - idx1
    color1 = gradient[idx1]
    color2 = gradient[idx2]
    color_in_between = [round(color1[i] * (1 - frac) + color2[i] * frac) for i in range(3)]
    return tuple(color_in_between)

So get_color_at(0) returns (0,0,0) and get_color_at(0.75) equals (153, 128, 102), which is this tan/brownish color in between orange and blue.
Now, how can I apply this to the original NumPy array? I shouldn't apply get_color_at directly to the NumPy array, since that would still give a 2d array, where each element is a 3-tuple. Instead, I think I want an array whose shape is (n, m, 3), so I can feed that to Pillow and create an RGB image.
If possible, I'd prefer to use vectorized operations whenever possible - my input arrays are quite large. If there is builtin-functionality to use a custom gradient, I would also love to use that instead of my own get_color_at function, since my implementation is pretty naive.
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: PIL: Generating Vertical Gradient Image. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PaulCornelius I really don't think so. It is not at all the same meaning of gradient. Your linked question talk about building some rainbow-like images, some gradient, in the sense of what people call gradient background in CSS/HTML. This one is just about colormap (gradient colormap. The word "gradient", which after all only means "progressive change", is also used in the context of colormaps)

@PaulCornelius Appreciate the feedback. I also think my question was sufficiently different as it stood, but in any case I've added some clarification for posterity.

Method 1: vectorization of your code
Your code is almost already vectorized. Almost all operations of it can work indifferently on a float or on an array of floats
Here is a vectorized version
def get_color_atArr(arr):
    assert (arr>=0).all() and (arr<=1).all()
    n=len(gradient)
    gradient.append(gradient[-1])
    gradient=np.array(gradient, dtype=np.uint8)
    pos = arr*(n-1)
    idx1 = pos.astype(np.uint8)
    idx2 = idx1+1
    frac = (pos - idx1)[:,:,None]
    color1 = gradient[idx1]
    color2 = gradient[idx2]
    color_in_between = np.round(color1*(1-frac) + color2*frac).astype(np.uint8)

Basically, the changes are,

the assert (can't use a<b<c notation with numpy arrays). Note that this assert iterates all values of array to check for assertion. That is not for free. So I included it because you did. But you need to be aware that this is not a compile-time verification. It does run code to check all values, which is a non-negligible part of all execution time of the code.
more an implementation choice than a vectorization step (a pure translation of your code would have translated that if x==1 into some np.where, or masks. But I am never comfortable with usage of == on floats any way. So I prefer my way. Which costs nothing. It is not another iteration on the image. It adds a sentinel (In Donald Kuth sense of "sentinel": a few bytes that avoid special cases) to the gradient color. So that, in the unlikely even that arr is really 1.0, the gradient happen between last color and last color).
frac is broadcasted in 3D array, so that it can be used as a coefficient on 3d arrays color1 and color2
Plus of course, int or floor can't be used on numpy arrays

Method 2: not reinventing the wheel
Matplotlib (and, I am certain, many other libraries) already have a whole colormap module to deal with this kind of transformations. Let's use it
thresh=np.linspace(0,1,len(gradient))
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', list(zip(thresh, np.array(gradient)/255.0)), N=256*len(gradient))
arr2 = cmap(arr)[:,:,:3]

This is building a custom colormap, using LinearSegmentedColormap, which takes, as 2nd argument, a list of pair (threshold, color).
Such as [(0, (0,0,0)), (0.3, (1,0,0)), (0.8, (0,1,0)), (1, (0,0,1))] for a color map that goes from black to red when x goes from 0 tom 0.3, then from red to green when x goes from 0.3 to 0.8, then from green to blue.
In this case, your gradient can be transformed to such a list, with just a zip with a linspace.
It takes a N= argument, since it creates a discretization of all possible colors (with interpolation in between). Here I take an exaggerated option (my N is more than the maximum number of different colors than can exist, once uint8d)
Also since it returns a RGBA array, and to remain strictly identical to what you did, I drop the A using [:,:,:3].
Of course, both method need the final translation into PIL, but you already know how to do that. For this one, it also needs mapping between 0 and 255, which I can do with your own code:
Image.fromarray((255 * arr).astype(np.uint8))
Note that, while using matplotlib colormap, you may want to take a tour at what that module has to offer. For example some of the zillions of already existing colormaps may suit you. Or some other way to build colors map non-linearly.

Appreciate your giving the vectorized example, it's very helpful to see some real examples of vectorized code for this. And thanks for mentioning LinearSegmentedColormap. This is exactly what I need. Tried your example and then dug into the documentation on that. It's fast and gives me the option of using drop-in default matplotlib colormaps in addition to my own gradients. +1
